# How do I make a horizontally laid out <dl> tag's <dt> the entire height of the <dl>?

Tags: css

I'm displaying a list of `<dl>` tags tags in my page. I'd like for the `<dd>` tags to not wrap when their content is long enough to go beyond the height of the `<dt>`.

What css will prevent this from happening?

[image: Example of wrapping issue]

Comment: so have the note be aligned.. ?

Comment: Right. Amadan's answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `margin-left` on the `<dd>` equal to the width of the `<dt>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `overflow: hidden` on `<dd>`.